# Swing JList font width

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am making a java program with produces a recept in a listbox, it will display the number of items, the item name and the price of the item. I need to pad the string so that the name is ruffly in the middle and the number of items and the cost are at ether side. Can you find the with in pixels of the strings then I can calculate the number of spaces needed to acheive the desired format. Thanks

Comment: See my updated code, I think that is what you really want! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you get the width of a string:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
FontMetrics fontMetrics = g2d.getFontMetrics();

int width = fontMetrics.stringWidth("aString");
int height = fontMetrics.getHeight();

...
```

But, as I read your question again I tought, why not use the [ListCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) in [JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html)? It works as you want:

http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/7509/jlistexample.jpg

And here is the code for it:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    JList list = new JList(new String[] { 
            "Hello", "World!", "as", "we", "know", "it" });

    list.setCellRenderer(new ListCellRenderer() {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                JList list, 
                Object value,
                int index, 
                boolean isSelected, 
                boolean cellHasFocus) {

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            if (isSelected)
                panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(
                    index == 0 ? 1 : 0, 1, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4,4,4,4);

            // index
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            panel.add(new JLabel("" + index), gbc);

            // "name"
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            panel.add(new JLabel("" + value), gbc);

            // cost
            gbc.weightx = 0;
            String cost = String.format("$%.2f", Math.random() * 100);
            panel.add(new JLabel(cost), gbc);


            return panel;
        }
    });

    frame.add(list);

    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```